# Javascript: Page load time

Tags: javascript, html

How do I calculate the time it takes to load a page and then display it? I am using a snippet I got online and modified it for display to my preference. Is there a better way to calculate the time it takes for a page to load?

Note: `ladezeit` is like date time in German.

```
<!--BEGIN_loadtime-->
<script type="text/javascript">

ladestart = new Date();

function ladezeit()
{
 current = new Date();
 dtime = current.getTime() - ladestart.getTime();
 loadtime = dtime/1000 +" seconds page load time.";
 document.getElementById("Ladezeit-Anzeige").innerHTML = loadtime;
}

</script>
<body onload="ladezeit()">
<div id="Ladezeit-Anzeige" style="position: absolute;  top: 5px; left: 10px;"></div>
<!--END_loadtime-->
```

Comment: If this is just for development, I'd simply use the Chrome Dev Console.  Control + Shift + J on any webpage, then click the Network tab and reload the page.

Comment: Not for development, it is to display on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page load speed depends on many factors, which includes the time it takes to load external files, such as CSS, JS, images, and etc and how fast the webserver responds. Using on page Javascript commands to detect the page load speed is flawed as it doesn't count how fast the server responds and etc.

To check how fast your page load, you might use tools, such as https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/.